# Load only part of associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, associations

I have an class `RequestAttachment` to my `ProjectRequestsArchive`

```
class ProjectRequestsArchive < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :request_attachment, 
           foreign_key: "request_id", 
           primary_key: "request_id", 
           required: true
end


class RequestAttachment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project_requests_archive,
               foreign_key: :request_id,
               primary_key: :request_id
end
```

Class `RequestAttachment` contains `BLOB` attribute.

So when I call `ProjectRequestsArchive.find(1054).request_attachment` it generates the SQL looks like

```
 RequestAttachment Load (24.7ms)  SELECT  `request_attachments`.* 
                                  FROM `request_attachments` 
                                  WHERE  `request_id` = 634 LIMIT 1
```

**Note:** This operation took about 10seconds, but I set up the index on `request_id` so now it takes up to 1s which is horrible too.

**Question:**

My question is, can I load `ID` of request only, without loading whole BLOB? I don't need to load it into memory, I just want to load the `ID`.

As I can see the SQL output above, there is `select request_attachments.*`.

When I use `ProjectRequestsArchive.find(1054).request_attachment.id` it also creates SQL: `select *`.

I would like to get SQL query, which selects ID only: `SELECT id from request_attachmens`. Is there any way to do it? I can't solve it by some kind of lazy load or something like that.

**Edit:**

**I forget to mention that, `ProjectRequestArchive.request_id` is mapped to `RequestAttachmet.request_id`.**

`RequestAttachment.id` is not same as `RequestAttachment.request_id`.
And I need to extract the `ID`.

Comment: Eh. Please correct key names; now all of them have the same name. Also, loading `RequestAttachment.where(...).pluck(id)` would solve your issue.

Comment: Key names, unfortunately, cannot be changed because of given schema.'
This solution looks ok, but I need to get it from the `ProjectRequestsArchive` class.

Comment: I don’t follow it at all. If all the keys are `request_id`, to get a `request_id` you might just **use the `request_id`** which is `634` in your example.

Comment: Well at the simplest form I just need to extract the `request_id` by using an associated object as shown  `ProjectRequestsArchive.find(1054).request_attachment.id` but without loading whole object, but only the ID.
There is another solution of course, but I am curious if there is something to do it this way.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forget to mention something. Please look at the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want sql to select specific columns on your database, you can use [select(*fields)](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select)

Use it like this:

```
Model.select("id, col1, col2").find() // and so on
```

Now the query log should be like this:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM "models" ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's a problem that, `ProjectRequestsArchive.find(1054).request_attachment.select(:id)` does not work. Select cannot be used at associated object.
There is a lot of options how to get the `ID` but I want to find out if there is a way to do this by the example above.

Comment: .select('associated_table.column')

Answer (score 1):

It should be lazy loaded out of the box. if you want ID only, check `ProjectRequestsArchive.first.request_id` and the `ProjectRequestsArchive.first.request_attachment` should be loaded after first touch.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forget to mention something. Please look at the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
RequestAttachmet.joins(:project_requests_archive).where(
  project_requests_archives: { id: 1054 }
).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works, but it's not exactly what I want.
I want to find a solution which uses associated object. So the solution I want to use should look something like this `ProjectRequestsArchive.find(1054).request_attachment.id`

Comment: Okay, Can you explain what worked and not worked ? So that it can be more clear about the actual requirement and can update answer.

Comment: This solution also uses associated object reference, I didn't get you on this. Is it just syntax preference ?

Comment: The `ProjectRequestsArchive` has associated model `RequestAttachment`. So if I want to load a related object I will use `ProjectRequestsArchive.first.request_attachment`. From that, I want to select only the `id` of the associated object and not all of the attributes.

Comment: **This solution also uses associated object reference, I didn't get you on this. Is it just syntax preference ?**
Yes, I just want to find the solution which uses specified syntax.

Comment: If thats the way, it will fire DB query as you mentioned in the post. Good Luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168392/discussion-between-jan-krupa-and-ashik-salman).